# Using parameters in neo4j query with spring

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

I have a repository which extends Neo4jRepository and would like to define a query like

```
@Query("match (x: Label {name: $name}) return x")
Collection<Label> f(@Param("name") String name);
```

I have this linked up to a request mapping.

When I make the request, say with name = "dog" I get that the following request is sent

```
match (x: Label {name: $name}) return x with params {name="dog"}
```

which returns nothing despite there being such things in my database, explicitly replacing the query to be

```
@Query("match (x: Label {name: "dog"}) return x")
Collection<Label> f(@Param("name") String name);
```

Produces the correct result.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

According to this page: https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions - you need something like:

```
@Query("match (x: Label {name: ?#{#name}}) return x")
```